# How to split data to each shard by user_id in Mongo?

Tags: mongodb

I have 3 shards

Instead of autosharding, can I define specifically shard1 only contains data that with user_id = 1 , and shard2 with user_id = 2 and shard3 with user_id = 3 ?

Comment: Normally it is better to shard on user_id and let mongo take care of where to place the ranges. Are you looking to contain all data for user_id on a single shard including other collections? Or is this just for the "user" collection?

Comment: I have two collections, one is "Users", and the other one is "Items".

Every User can have many Items.
So, I want to split Item collection into each shard by user_id.
Shard1 only contain the Items with belong to user_id = 1
Shard2 only contain the Items with belong to user_id = 2
Shard3 only contain the Items with belong to user_id = 3

Comment: I am not very experienced with manually assigning chunks however maybe you could do something with migrate: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/administration/sharding/#migrating-chunks and pre-splitting http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/administration/sharding/#create-chunks-pre-splitting ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go the manual splitting and sharding route and turn off the balancer, but a more scalable solution might be to try out the new [shard tagging](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Tag+Aware+Sharding) feature in 2.2

Kristina's [example](http://www.kchodorow.com/blog/2012/07/25/controlling-collection-distribution/) is intended to show how to control collection distribution but you could adapt it for your purposes, say tag chunks for specific user ranges in both collections to ensure their locality on a particular shard.

You still have to manage this yourself in some way, but it at least takes the burden off you from a chunk management and migration perspective.